# How many additional robots would be required?

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

> A contract is to be completed in 52 days and 125 identical robots were employed, each operational for 7 hours a day. After 39 days, five-seventh of the work was completed. How many additional robots would be required to complete the work on time, if each robot is now operational for 8 hours a day?
>
> (A) 50 (B) 89
> (C) 146 (D) 175

My trial: Given that

125 identical robots, each operational for 7 hours a day, complete work in 52 days
so the work of 1 robot per hour$=1/(125\cdot52\cdot7)$

Now, after 39 days left over work $=1-5/7=2/7$ is to be completed in left 52-39=13 days

suppose $x$ number of additional robots are required to complete the left over work then
$$\frac27=\frac{13\cdot(125+x)\cdot8}{52\cdot125\cdot7}$$
$$1=\frac{(125+x)}{125}$$
$$125+x=125\implies x=0$$

But my answer doesn't match any of given options. I don't know where I am wrong. Please give correct solution with explanation to this problem.

thanks

Comment: In addition to my answer, the reason your answer is incorrect regardless and gets as result $x = 0$ is because of your initial assumption "125 identical robots, each operational for 7 hours a day, complete work in 52 days". That's not correct. It also perfectly explains why you got $x = 0$ :)

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful **and** [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $n$ the number of robot hours of work produced so far. We have:

$$n = 39 \times 7 \times 125 = 34125$$

In total $N$ robot hours are needed:

$$\frac{5}{7}N = n \quad \longrightarrow\quad N = 47775$$

We have $N - n$ robot hours work left, and $(52 - 39) \times8 = 104$ hours. Thus the number of additional robots needed is:

$$\frac{N - n}{104} - 125 = 6.25$$

Since we can't have fractional robots, we need $7$.

I have no idea where the multiple choice answers came from, from napkin paper math $5/7 \approx 0.71$ vs $39/52 =0.75$ even discounting that we now work more hours per day, adding $50$ robots to $125$ is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

**COMMENT**.-A way to see none of the given possible answer is correct.
$$39\cdot125\cdot7=\frac{5T}{7}\cdots\cdots (1)\\(A)\text{ gives } 13\cdot175\cdot8=\frac{2T}{7}\\(B)\text{ gives } 13\cdot214\cdot8=\frac{2T}{7}\\(C)\text{ gives } 13\cdot271\cdot8=\frac{2T}{7}\\(D)\text{ gives } 13\cdot300\cdot8=\frac{2T}{7}$$
Taking the quotients of $(1)$ by  each of the fourth letters $A,B,C,D$ the LHS  is equal to $\dfrac 52$ but the  corresponding LHS's are $1.875,\space1.5332...,1.2107....,1.09375....$ respectively and none of them is equal to $\dfrac 52$.

The answer $6.25$ given below by orlp is correct despite its lack of meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The number of robots is actually irrelevant. It is just a side calculation. 125x7 is 875 hours a day. Multiplied by 39 we have 34,125 work done. Since we know that 29,250 is 5/7 of the work we can divide by 5 and multiply by 2 to get 2/7 of the work. That will land us 13,650 hours of work left.

11,700/8 divided by 125=13.65

This is not enough. The smallest amount possible is actually some number I CBA to figure out. The reason why is because it won't any of the options **but** it will be less than 1 of the options. Meaning every option works out fine. The smallest possible number of extra robots required out of that option is A so there is your answer.

However, if you want to be annoying to your assessor, just tell them that D is the correct answer. If D is the wrong answer then all of them are. The reason is because any less robots than D will be slower.